Обновление приложения, написанного на Kivy
Пишу небольшое приложение для своих нужд на Python с использованием KivyMD и Kivy.
Для сохранения введенных пользователем данных использую kivy.storage.JsonStore. Собираю в apk приложение через buildozer.
Но при изменении приложения все данные стираются.
Как сделать так, чтобы при обновлении приложения данные сохранялись?
